# JQuery. Remove a previous sibling in the DOM tree

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the next code dynamically created using JQuery. Theere are multiple `row` class divs placed one under the other.

```
<div class="row">
    ....
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="line_type"></div>
   <div class="download_value"></div>
   <div class="flag"></div>
   <div class="email"></div>
   <div class="prize"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    ....
</div>
```

After i create these `divs` I have a "pointer" to a specific div which is of class `row`. In JQuery, how do i make it so I go down the DOM tree, until i reach the div of class `line_type` and `download_value` and remove them both, and also I'd like to go one more node down, at the div of type `email` and change some of it's CSS attributes.

I was not able to find anything on the web, maybe it's cause i'm a noob at these still.

Comment: Create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), to show your DOM structure and what you have tried so far.

Comment: You mean you just want to remove all `.line_type` and `.download_value` elements, and edit the style of all `.email` elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I have a "pointer" to a specific div which is of class row* ->

Assuming that you have the `this` object of the corresponding div with class `row`.. then you can use `.find` to get the `line_type` and `download_value` inside that div.

```
$(this).find('.line_type').remove();
$(this).find('.download_value').remove();
```

Then you can use the same `.find` to get the div with class `email` and access the `.css`

```
$(this).find('.email').css(/* You code*/);
```

Comment: oh... that looks like the thing i'm looking for :D The `find()` function. let me try it out

Comment: and yeah... i meant the "this object of the corresponding div with class `row`" :) hehe

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `row_pointer` points to the row in question:

```
$('.line_type, .download_value', row_pointer).remove();
$('.email', row_pointer).css(...);
```

Comment: Not all of the divs of those classes. Just some.

Comment: @AndreiBogdan Well the `row_pointer` inside those `$(..)` will just get the _some_ div you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

check this out

```
$('div.row').bind('click', function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $('div.line_type, div.download_value', $this).remove();
      $('div.email', $this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YvyE3/